# How to find if UIwebview is using cache to load the data in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching, uiwebview

## How do I find if the UIWebview is using cache data or fetching from new content from the network. I need to find this in the code.

I am not using NSURLConnection to get the data and load in the UIWebview

Just simply loading a resource in the UIWebview by

[self.webview loadRequest:request];  //(request can be a url)

Answer (score -1):

This is covered in some of the Apple documentation and (older) NSHipster post.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001843-BAJEAIEE

http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/

Comment: These links do not answer the OP's question, they just talk about caching policies. They want to actually find out whether a given request was retrieved from the cache or not.